# Terraform: is it possible to declare a list variable that allows mixed types? How?

Tags: terraform

The [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/type-constraints#collection-types) suggest it is not possible,  but I wanted to be sure.

> list(...): a sequence of values identified by consecutive whole numbers starting with zero.
>
> The keyword list is a shorthand for list(any), which accepts any element type **as long as every element is the same type**. This is for compatibility with older configurations; for new code, we recommend using the full form.

(emphasis mine)

To give a more tangible scenario, let's say I would like to create a module that takes as input a variable list, and for each element it will extract different attributes depending on a `kind` attribute. Example:

```
module "mod1" {
  source = "./path/to/module1.tf"

  my_list = [
    {
      kind = "type1"
      field_of_type1 = "foo"
    },
    {
      kind = "type2"
      field_of_type2 = "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: No this is not possible yet as `tftypes` does not yet utilize generics (and I am unsure if that is on the roadmap or not). The documentation is indeed correct, and the `any` `tftypes` is equivalent the `any` type in Go. Doc is here: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-go/tftypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've described here is, in programming language theory, called a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) or "sum type".

Terraform's type system does not have explicit support for tagged unions but you can describe something that is functionally equivalent to it using a mixture of optional object attributes and validation rules, by creating an object type that only allows one of its attributes to be set at a time. Which attribute the caller chooses therefore acts as the "tag" which you can use to make decisions in your module's logic.

For example:

```
variable "my_list" {
  type = list(object({
    type1 = optional(object({
      field_of_type1 = string
    }))
    type2 = optional(object({
      field_of_type2 = string
    }))
  }))

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for item in var.my_list :
      length([for v in item : v if v != null]) == 1
    ])
    error_message = "Each element must have exactly one attribute set to decide the item type."
  }
}
```

The type constraint states that zero or more of these attributes may be set, but the validation rule adds the additional constraint that *exactly one* must be set, which is what gives this the same expressiveness as a tagged union type.

The call to a module with a variable like this would look slightly different than what you showed but contains effectively the same information, just structured a little differently:

```
module "mod1" {
  source = "./path/to/module1.tf"

  my_list = [
    {
      type1 = {
        field_of_type1 = "foo"
      }
    },
    {
      type2 = {
        field_of_type2 = "bar"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Inside the module you'll presumably want to treat these objects differently depending on which of the attributes was set. You can do that by filtering the list by a particular attribute being non-null. For example, the following local value will contain all of the items of `type1`:

```
locals {
  type1_things = tolist([
    for item in var.my_list : item.type_1
    if item.type_1 != null
  ])
}
```